# Sum of infinite cosine series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm not sure how to search for this.

> Evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)}{2^k}.$$

I thought about expanding $\cos(x)$ as a Taylor series, but that didn't go anywhere. Any hints?

Comment: Express $\cos(k)$ in terms of $e^{ik}$ and $e^{-ik}$. We get two geometric series.

Comment: You are welcome. One can also get it using trig identities, but it is messy, while the $\frac{e^{ik}+e^{-ik}}{2}$ way is structurally quite natural.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Even more efficient is to write $\cos (k)=\text{Re}(e^{ik})$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\cos x =\text{Re}\left(e^{ix}\right)$$

Then, the series of interest is

$$\text{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{i}}{2}\right)^k\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

**Amusement Time**

Firstly I thought about a joke, namely: let's take the series, and white it like:

$$S = \frac{e^i}{2} + \frac{e^{2i}}{4} + \frac{e^{3i}}{8} + \frac{e^{4i}}{16} + \ldots $$

Now:

$$S = \frac{e^i}{2}\cdot\left[1 + \frac{e^i}{2} + \frac{e^{2i}}{4} + \frac{e^{3i}}{8} + \frac{e^{4i}}{16} + \ldots \right] = \frac{e^i}{2}\cdot (1 + S)$$

Then re-arranging the terms to get S:

$$S = \frac{e^i}{2-e^i}$$

Now we have to take the **Real part**:

$$\Re \frac{e^i}{2 - e^i} = \Re \frac{i\sin(1) + \cos(1)}{2 - i\sin(1) -\cos(1)} = \frac{\cos(1)}{2-\cos(1)} $$

**Unfortunately this is not the sum of that series.**

But I guess that a similar road shall be undertaken because **the sum of that series is** (thanks to Mathematica)

$$S = \frac{1 - 2\cos(1)}{4\cos(1) - 5}$$